# AndroidX Security EncryptedSharedPreferences v1.1.0 /w API 21 issue

Tags: android, security, androidx, encrypted-shared-preference

I decided to use new EncryptedSharedPreferences from AndroidX Security library. Since the app is supporting API 21 and higher, I decided to try out this new v1.1.0-alpha02 version, since it supports API 21+

So, I succeded to make the implementation for API 23+, but for older versions where Android KeyStore is not supported, I couldn't make it right, and there are no exact instructions how the master key should be created to make it work somehow.

The code for initializing SharedPrefs:

```
EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
        "prefs_name",
        createMasterKey(),
        App.appContext,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
    )
```

with this function for creating master key

```
   private fun createMasterKey(): String {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC)
        } else {
            val alias = "my_alias"
            val start: Calendar = GregorianCalendar()
            val end: Calendar = GregorianCalendar()
            end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 30)

            val spec = KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(App.appContext)
                .setAlias(alias)
                .setSubject(X500Principal("CN=$alias"))
                .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(abs(alias.hashCode()).toLong()))
                .setStartDate(start.time).setEndDate(end.time)
                .build()

            val kpGenerator: KeyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                "RSA",
                "AndroidKeyStore"
            )
            kpGenerator.initialize(spec)
            val kp: KeyPair = kpGenerator.generateKeyPair()
            
            kp.public.toString()
        }
    }
```

I found this solution somewhere out there, but it's not verified (no confirmation that it actually works), but it seems it should work.

When using this code block for API 21 and 22, the error appears on creating EncryptedSharedPreferences, and it says:
Method threw 'com.google.crypto.tink.shaded.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException' exception.
Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).

Did someone find the solution for this implementation, or do you know why is this happening?
I think this would help a lot of people, since there is no exact explanation what should this master key contain.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I experience the same error when using EncryptedFile of the androidx.security.crypto library. It only happens on one device _(Samsung S9+ (Android 10))_  tested directly so far and another device _(Pixel 2 (Android 11))_ according to the comment of another user.

Please also refer to the issue:
[Google Issue Tracker - Related Issue 168407869](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168407869)

Comment: @goldensoju in the issue tracker you concluded this wasn't a crypto issue--what was it, please?

Comment: @Oded I assume bad code that corrupted the data being sent to the library.

Comment: @goldensoju OK, thanks. In our case it just seems like random corruption for one user when creating the SharedPreferences file in the first place. A reinstall cleared the issue.

Comment: The code has been deprecated.

Comment: This problem is likely related to open [Android Issue 164901843](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/164901843) which throws the exact same error.

Answer (score 30):

Add to manifest
`android:allowBackup="false" android:fullBackupContent="false"`

Because after uninstalling the application you still have backed up your crypto file which you definitely can't decrypt after installing a new version.

Comment: This will prevent backup of every possible file, not just of the secured shared preferences

Comment: Should we add `android:fullBackupContent="false"`? It refers to a file with storage settings, not a boolean value.

Comment: I think that this is the right solution if you encrypt your shared preferences while using an encryption key from the KeyStore. Android can automatically backup almost every file (like shared prefs) but cannot backup your keys, so your backup becomes useless.

Answer (score 12):

Here is what I have done, it seems to have fixed the error. Instead of removing the auto-backup feature, just do this:

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
 android:allowBackup="true"
 android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
```

In backup_descriptor.xml

```
<full-backup-content>
    <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="keys.xml"/>
</full-backup-content>
```

keys.xml being the encrypted shared preference file name. Exclude all encrypted shared preference files this way.

Also, I am using
implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha02'

for now, seems like everything is working well with this setup.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work on NOKIA 7 Plus with Android 10, be careful.  I've only fixed it using version 1.1.0-alpha01. ;)

Comment: Same, only 1.1.0-alpha01 helped me.

Comment: @es0329 have you had any compatibility issues when switching to alpha01 with not being able to read data encrypted with alpha03?

Comment: @luxo Sorry I really don't recall. I quickly reverted to stay on alpha01 when I saw the crashes during development.

Comment: For my part, once data was encrypted on alpha02, it crashed if I tried reverting to alpha01. So Im stuck on alpha02, but I am currently crash free in production.

Comment: @SeanBlahovici Interesting. I just want from alpha03 to alpha01 in a production app with quite a few users and have not run into any issues yet (knock on wood). I did a lot of testing switching between the two versions in testing (03 -> 01 and vice versa) and never experienced any crash related to decrypting. What were the crashes you were getting?

Comment: 1.1.0-alpha01 works for me. 02 crashes

Answer (score 11):

I can fix the `InvalidProtocolBufferException` in two ways, though I don't like either of them:

Use an older version of `security-crypto`

```
implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha01'
```

Use the latest (at the time of writing) version of `security-crypto`, but with a forced older version of tink:

```
implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation('com.google.crypto.tink:tink-android') {
    version {
        strictly '1.4.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: `1.0.0-alpha02` works fine for me, but `1.0.0-alpha03` is crashing on Android 10

Comment: Strictly setting a tink-android version does not work in my case but using alpha01 does. I tried with alpha02 as well but still get this crash.

Comment: None of those options work for me, I've created a new bug on Google's side: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210008257

Comment: this work around method works for me

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE: Errors on different devices. The result isn't the solution.**

I setup the android propreties "fullbackupcontent" this way in my Manifest

```
android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
```

Here is my backup_descriptor file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>

    <!-- App data isn't included in user's backup unless client-side encryption is enabled. -->
    <include domain="file" path="." requireFlags="clientSideEncryption" />

<!-- Exclude specific shared preferences that contain GCM registration Id -->
<!--    <exclude domain=["file" | "database" | "sharedpref" | "external" | "root"]-->
<!--    path="string" />-->
</full-backup-content>
```

Now my app is working again & I can keep allowing backups.

Source :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#define-device-conditions

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#IncludingFiles

Comment: What is the correct solution, then? Need to exclude the files manually?

Comment: same here, what to do?

Answer (score -1):

*Here is a different solution that I found on google issue tracker.*

As google document stated, "Note: The methods in both the EncryptedFile class and the `EncryptedSharedPreferences` class aren't thread-safe." You need to wrap the calling in a synchronised method.

```
@synchronized
fun createSharedPreferences() {
    val keyGenParameterSpec = MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC
    val masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(keyGenParameterSpec)
    prefs = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
        "file-name",
        masterKeyAlias,
        context,
        PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
        PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM)
}
```

src. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147480931#comment19